# How can I get the new Templates to work in Blender 2.79?

Tags: python, interface

The Blender manual states in [this article](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/app_templates.html) that 2.79 introduces a new Template System. This empowers the user to dynamically change aspects of Blender, like the startup splash screen, keyboard layouts, certain scripts, etc. The beauty of this is that users can create their own application on top of Blender when exploiting this.

I was following the manual as best as I could, but my templates never actually show up. This is the content of the folder I'm currently using:

[image: Templates Used]

The folder location is set via environment variables `BLENDER_USER_CONFIG` and `BLENDER_USER_SCRIPTS`. So they are not at their Default, but this has always been working nicely for me.

I would now expect to either be able to switch to that template either using the Splash Screen or the File Menu. But my custom template isn't listed anywhere. What am I missing? Even if I manually generate a ZIP file and use `Install Template from File`, Blender puts the files in that location just fine, but never actually shows or loads the template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it doesn't work with Environment Variables at this moment because of this bug:
https://developer.blender.org/T52442

I hoped it should be solved by this fix:
https://developer.blender.org/rB2aa2bec43a7f1fa214833c73d033ae1785c600f3
... but it still does not work even in the most recent builds.

But regardless of Environment Variables, you should still be able to test your template by moving the `bl_app_templates_user` folder with your template to Blender's user directory `c:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\startup`

So it will look like this

[image]

[image]

Make sure you no longer have a duplicate of your theme in the previous path (Blender program directory).

Comment: On another note, can we edit the splash now? Last I remember it was locked

Comment: Yes, if you put splash.png to the template folder, it will replace the original one - I have already tested it.

Comment: @JanKadeřábek I've added a comment to the bug report as well, maybe that increases the attention to this. Copying the files locally works, though that eliminates the advantages of a portable installation alltogether.

Comment: I noticed your comment there, thanks. I think it is just an early implementation of this feature so I am sure / hope we will get lots of changes & fixes soon.