# Custom Layout and Startup files for additional Workspaces - Blender 2.79

Tags: scripting

I just read the documentation and came across this marvelous option to customize the entire layout. There´s a directory hierarchy, startup.blend, userpref.blend and a **required .py file to register and unregister the layout**. But there´s no template to do that.
Could anyone please help me out? Also there´s an option to add a custom splash screen. So I guess that would also have to be called from the .py file that is required. 
The name of the .py file is not mentioned. And (regular) custom layouts are only created from inside blender.
If you go to **FILE>APPLICATION TEMPLATES** you will see what I mean.

Please help. This is amazing, but there are no templates to do anything like this.
Thanks.

Comment: The new templates feature is not the same as screen layouts. Do you want to switch between completely different startup settings or just create your own custom screen layouts?

Comment: custom screen layouts. like the one´s comming in 2.8. I need a .py file to hide that stuff. I found this. But can´t read it much: https://developer.blender.org/source/bf-app-templates/browse/trunk/blender_lite

Comment: That "application templates" is a future feature that is only in early development and can be expected in some future release. The templates in 2.79 is explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/90503/935).

Comment: What about if I want to add custom shortcut keys and addons already activated?

Comment: Custom shortcuts and enabled addons are saved in the startup file, so yes these can be setup differently for each template.